# Babel unexpected token ':' during let clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the following code segment:

```
  let baseUrl = '/';
  let url = req.originalUrl || '/';

  let config: ExpressEngineConfig = {
    directives: [ App ],
```

when I attempt to compile this file using babel, I get the error

```
SyntaxError: server.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (37:12)
```

The error points at the `:` character as the unexpected token. Am I missing something? Here's my `.babelrc`. Thanks for any help

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a type annotation in `let config: ExpressEngineConfig`, which is not part of JS (es2015 or otherwise).

If you're using [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) type annotations, you'll need to enable the plugin [as described in the Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-flow/):

> ```
> {
>   "plugins": ["syntax-flow"]
> }
> ```

If you're using Typescript, you'll need to compile that to JS before running Babel.

Comment: The code looks a lot like the code [presented here](https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/); I wonder if the annotation isn't the result of cutting and pasting a bit too much from an original TS source (given that it's supposed to be run by Node directly).

Comment: @robertklep yep, this is the location I got it from. Just trying to get this into some form I can actually run

Comment: @SyntacticFructose just strip the annotation and you should be good. Or, enable Flow and let it/Babel strip them (I'm not sure who does that).

Comment: @SyntacticFructose it'll probably work if you remove `: ExpressEngineConfig` (so it becomes `let config = { ... }`).